Remove Sub Steps from allure report
Ho to Remove Sub Steps from allure report
I am getting the steps inside this allure.step printed this the report need to remove those sub steps and need to add screenshot to it.
enter image description here
Expected Result :
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
